# How do I root my device with Mac OS X?

Tags: rooting, macos

Similar to [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device), except using Mac OS X.

Everywhere I try to find the answer to leads me to Windows applications. Are there any guides or tools for OS X?

Answer (score 2):

It's very device-specific, of course, so you'll have to follow the directions given for the device.

Generally it works to follow the Linux directions for the device, except that you need ADB for Mac OS X.

Comment: Devs always scratch their own itch first. It depends heavily on the device maintainer's preferences and how wide spread a device is and maybe also how sexy it is (pro/mid-range/low-end). Samsung devices have Mac support for example ([heimdall for mac](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/downloads)). Plus: System developing for Android requires not Win nor MacOs but Linux.